# How to add html to an array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, drupal

I am trying to add some html code before each tag printed as an array element.  

**My code:**

```
  $term_links = array();

  foreach ($vars['node']->taxonomy as $term) 
  {
    $term_links[] = l($term->name, 'taxonomy/term/' . $term->tid,
      array(
        'attributes' => array(
          'title' => $term->description
    )));
  }

  $vars['node_terms'] = implode(', ', $term_links);
```

At the moment the tags are printed seperated by a comma. I would like to add a small image before each tag element using `img src="tag.png"`  **How can I do this?**

**EDIT - My current Code, still not working.**

```
 if (module_exists('taxonomy')) {

$img  = 'some html';
$text = $img . $term->name;
$path = 'taxonomy/term/' . $term->tid;


$term_links = array();
foreach ($vars['node']->taxonomy as $term) {



  $term_links[] = l($text, $path, array(
    'html' => TRUE,
      'attributes' => array(
        'title' => $term->description
    )));
 }
   $vars['node_terms'] = implode(', ', $term_links);
 }
}
```

Comment: Move these lines: $img  = 'some html';
$text = $img . $term->name;
$path = 'taxonomy/term/' . $term->tid inside foreach () loop...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dupal's l() function has an option "html" you can set it to TRUE and use IMG + TITLE as a title.

Here is the example:

```
$img  = '<img src="..." />';
$text = $img . $term->name;
$path = 'taxonomy/term/' . $term->tid;

$term_links[] = l($text, $path, array(
  'html'       => TRUE,
  'attributes' => array(
    'title' => $term->description
  )
));
```

Comment: Thanks, I've changed the code to yours but now it only prints the images, but no tags...

Comment: Code i posted must be inside foreach() loop, in your example it's outside of loop. Obviously there is no term->name before you enter the foreach() loop.

Comment: Ah, you're right! Many thanks! Using this method, can I also add Html code at the end of each tag?